# How do you pass a logger using HttpClientFactory and a PolicyRegistry?

Tags: c#, polly, httpclientfactory

I've been reading [this](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/passing-an-ilogger-to-polly-policies) which seems to have a way of doing what I want.

I've got something similar obviously, but within the `PolicyContextExtensions` the `context.TryGetValue` takes `PolicyContextItems`. This shows as an undefined object for me.

Where does this come from and how is this set?

For reference here is the `PolicyContextExtensions` class:

```
public static class PolicyContextExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetLogger(this Context context, out ILogger logger)
    {
        if(context.TryGetValue(PolicyContextItems.Logger, out var loggerObject) && loggerObject is ILogger theLogger)
        {
            logger = theLogger;
            return true;
        }

        logger = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Polly's [Context](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Context.Dictionary.cs#L11) class is basically a `Dictionary<string, object>`.
Which means you can register any kind of data with an arbitrary string.

In the tutorial Stephen has created a new context like this:

```
var context = new Context($"GetSomeData-{Guid.NewGuid()}", new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { PolicyContextItems.Logger, _logger }
});
```

- The arbitrary string is `$"GetSomeData-{Guid.NewGuid()}"`
- Where as the data is a `Dictionary<string, object>`

So, he had created a yet another dictionary inside the dictionary. Why? Because with this you can group the to be passed data on a method basis (like `GetSomeData...`)

In this case the [`PolicyContextItems.Logger`](https://github.com/stevejgordon/PollyLoggingContextSample/blob/master/PollyLoggingContextSample/Policies/PolicyContextItems.cs) is just a string constant for `logger`:

```
public static class PolicyContextItems
{
    public const string Logger = "logger";
}
```

---

If you want to avoid nesting dictionaries but you want to group them on a method basis then you can simply prefix the keys and use the [`Add`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/02bc9cfe8f0d04ea34c29c0168e1eaed7455ca80/src/Polly.Shared/Context.Dictionary.cs#L58) method:

```
var context = new Context();
context.Add("GetSomeData-Logger", _logger);
context.Add("GetSomeData-XYZ", _xyz);
```

---

All the above solutions are explicitly setting the key of the data, which is error-prone. You need to know the name not just during the Policy creation but whenever you want to access the passed data as well.

A more convenient approach is to store the key next to the *setter* and *getter* methods:

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    private static readonly string LoggerKey = "LoggerKey";

    public static Context WithLogger(this Context context, ILogger logger)
    {
        context[LoggerKey] = logger;
        return context;
    }

    public static ILogger GetLogger(this Context context)
    {
        if (context.TryGetValue(LoggerKey, out object logger))
        {
            return logger as ILogger;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This example was taken from the [official documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-and-Context-Data#example-varying-the-ilogger-used-within-an-onretry-delegate).

Comment: Excellent answer. Many thanks!